# javascript inside a html script tag is not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Something simple but I can't seem to find the right google words to answer my question

I have the following cshtml file

```
@using BAT.ViewModels
@model DocPortfolio

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Describe Your Project";
}

<h2>Provide a Description of Your Project</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("GetDocumentPortfolio", "DocPortfolio"))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Description of project sizes?
        </legend>

        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.SelectedProjectSize, Model.ProjectSizes)

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            What is the main form of communication for your team?
        </legend>
        <label class="radio">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.CommunicationType, true, new { id =  "Verbal" }) 
            @Html.Label("Verbal", "Verbal")

        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.CommunicationType, false, new { id = "Written" }) 
            @Html.Label("Written", "Written")

        </label>
    </fieldset>

    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Generate Documents</button>
    </div>
}
<script language="text/javascript" >
$(function () {
    $('input, select, button').change(function () {
        window._eqatecmonitor.trackFeature("PortfolioFormItem." + $(this).attr("id"));
        alert("PortfolioFormItem." + $(this).attr("id"));
    });

    $('input').change(function () {
        window._eqatecmonitor.trackFeatureValue("PortfolioFormValue" + $(this).attr("name") + "." + $(this).val());
        alert("PortfolioFormValue" + $(this).attr("name") + "." + $(this).val());
    });

    $('select').change(function () {
        window._eqatecmonitor.trackFeatureValue("PortfolioFormValue" + $(this).attr("id") + "." + $(this).text());
        alert("PortfolioFormValue" + $(this).attr("id") + "." + $(this).text());
    });
});
```

if i copy and paste the code inside the script tag my jquery works as expected, but it doesn't work when the page loads.

I have tried using

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

but this isn't working either. Can anyone point my tired eyes in the right direction ?

Comment: Maybe you need the close script tag? `</script>`

Comment: You need to use type, `<script type="text/javascript" >`. change `language` to `type` or remove that attribute.